# How do I make links inside my Javascript controlled div to work?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a tooltip using this code from Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joktrpkz/7/

```
var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
var sel = window.getSelection();
var rel1= document.createRange();
rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
var rel2= document.createRange();
rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        debugger;
        var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
        ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top)*100/(rb1.top-rb2.top) + 'px'; //this will place ele below the selection
        ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left)*100/(rb1.left-rb2.left) + 'px'; //this will align the right edges together

        //code to set content

        ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Everything works fine but I noticed the html links on the tooltip no longer work.

I think the mouseup event is affecting the links but I am not sure.

What is preventing the links from working and how can I fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the mousedown event that hides the tooltip. If you look on this lines:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
});
```

You will notice that when you hold down the click on the tooltip, it disappears and therefore you are clicking on "nothing". If you comment out that part, it'll work.

Comment: Very true. You are very correct. Can you kindly suggest to me how to hide the div on mouseclick outside the div?

Comment: Yes, here is an example of a way you can do it, with jQuery though. https://jsfiddle.net/joktrpkz/41/

Comment: Can you help me with a Javascript implementation? JQuery is not allowed on the project I am working on.

Comment: I was afraid you will say that. Here is a pure javascript implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/joktrpkz/42/